# Custom Diplay name Json in android

Tags: regex, json

I'm parsing a json file like this :

```
JSONObject stationJson = array.optJSONObject(i);
Station s = new Station();
s.setName(stationJson.optString("name"));
s.setTimestamp(stationJson.optString("last_update"));
s.setNumber(stationJson.optInt("number"));
```

This is the json file :

```
{
"number": 123,
"contract_name" : "7500 - London",
"name": "nom station",
"address": "adresse indicative",
}
```

I would like to display just the "London" in the name section not the Number.

I found this Code Snippet but I don't know how to use it :

```
 private String buildDisplayName(String name) {
        String regexp = "[\\d\\s]*([a-zA-Z](.*)$)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
        if (m.find()) {
            return m.group();
        }
        return name;
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: by `not the Number`you mean `7500`.

Comment: is the name always formatted in the same way? By this I mean first a number, followed by a space, a hyphen and another space, and then the name you actually want?

Comment: Yes I mean the 7500  and yes it's always a number followed by a space!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always the exact same format why not use `substring` so you still understand your own code. For example, use:

```
String test = stationJson.optString("name");
s.setName(test.substring(test.indexOf("-")+2));
```

This gets the string value from your name, 2 positions from the position of the hyphen ( the "-").

If you want to work with regex, that's great, but if you don't really know how it works, I wouldn't recommend it. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) might give you an idea of what the code snippet you pasted is actually doing. And [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) is a tutorial about it.

Comment: Thank you! It worked great. I'm reading the links you posted. It make sense!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) regex can be really useful (and in way more complex situations than this one) as long as you know what you're doing.